# How can I correctly position a UIImageView inside a UITableViewCell?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have a custom UITableViewCell loaded from a nib. In it are three UIImageView views. In the `-(UITableViewCell*) tableView:(UITableView*) cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath` method I check a property for each row and determine whether each one is visible. If they are not visible, I shift the x position of the image so that there are no empty spaces. I am using:

```
cell.imageView1.hidden = YES;
cell.imageView2.hidden = YES;
cell.imageView3.hidden = YES;

int x = 0;

CGRect frame1 = cell.imageView1.frame;

if (property1)
{
    cell.imageView1.hidden = NO;
    frame1.origin.x = x;
    x += SPACING;
}

CGRect frame2 = cell.imageView2.frame;

if (property2)
{
    cell.imageView2.hidden = NO;
    frame2.origin.x = x;
    x += SPACING;
}

// etc...
```

For some reason, when the table is initially shown, the images are in the wrong location, but if I scroll up and down so that the cell is not shown then shown again, the image location goes to its correct place. What is causing this?

Comment: Where do you have that code? Post text of whole method...

Comment: FYI: when you are scrolling you are reusing cells. So you could start from that.

Comment: I know, but if they have static positions, why is it shifting?

Comment: Why do you shift image if it is hidden?

Comment: Sorry, incorrectly swapped those. Edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Felipe for pointing me to the right solution. In my UITableViewCell subclass I overrode the layoutSubviews method to properly layout the images there according to their state.

Comment: You're welcome :) but the correct way to this here is to mark my answer as the correct one. I would appreciate it.

Comment: But it wasn't the right answer. The right answer was to override teh layoutSubviews method.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure If I understood your code. But you could try calling `setNeedsLayout` after changing the frames.

```
[cell setNeedsLayout]
```

This method indicates that this views needs to layout on the next rendering.